# Haskell statements in GHCi being interrupted seems to break cmd

Tags: haskell, cmd, ghci

I'm just beginning with Haskell and playing around with GHCi in cmd. After trying out [something I saw on PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19562/73884), I ran into an issue. Whenever I interrupt `fix` with control-C, everything dies:

```
C:\Users\Scrooble>ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.Function
Prelude Data.Function> fix (\x -> x + 1)
In^tCerrupte
d.
C:\Users\Scrooble>Prelude Data.Function> exit
```

(hangs)

The `^` and `C` were my keyboard interrupt. The `exit` is mine as well.

`Cerrupted` is right! What is going on?! I seem to have halfway exited GHCi. When I interrupt the `exit` (prompt is `Prelude Data.Function>` again) and `:q` it, cmd sometimes just closes and sometimes prompts me with `C:\Users\Scrooble` once more; however, when this happens, the first character of all my commands is ignored!

```
C:\Users\Scrooble>exit
'xit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program, or batch file.
```

0.o

Am I alone in this? Is there a `fix` (ha) (other than not doing stupid things)?

HP ProBook 4535s, with Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit. AMD A4-3300M APU processor.

The same happens in PowerShell as well. In Git Bash, the window freezes after I interrupt the `fix`.

#### Edit:

I've now experienced this when interrupting other infinite recursion, like my mergesort that (whoops!) didn't treat singletons as necessarily sorted.

Comment: Where's the `exit` come from? It's not exactly clear what you typed and what the system replied. Your OS version is relevant. Your computer model number is irrelevant, and your hardware is probably altogether irrelevant, but it's never a bad idea to mention the general sort of processor (x86_64, ARM, etc.) when you're getting strange behavior.

Comment: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14150

Comment: (1) I also intermittently get this issue with cmd and GHC 8.2.2 -- it's not just with `fix`, though I haven't figured out how to consistently reproduce yet. (2) @ja. Note that the ticked you have linked to is about PowerShell, and not cmd.

Comment: @duplode, have you opened a ticket for that? Even inconsistent problems are worth looking into, and Tamar Christina is pretty darn good at tracking down pesky Windows trouble.

Comment: @dfeuer I'll do it -- I'll just wait until I see it again, just to make sure I won't misremember anything. It shouldn't take long for it to happen again...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running [Haskell platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform) installed on Windows. I used to to that, but these days I run everything through [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org), so I may remember the following incorrectly.

IIRC, though, when you attempt to run `ghci` in Windows, it explicitly prints a warning that `ghci` is known to have problems with break commands on Windows, and that you should instead run GHCi via the batch command `ghcii.bat`.

Back when I used the Haskell platform, I always ran with `ghcii.bat`, and typically didn't have those problems. I've always used Haskell from within Git Bash, which is my default CLI on Windows, so that could be a determining factor as well.

These days I use Stack on Windows 10, and from within Git Bash, I can't reproduce the problem:

```
$ stack ghci
Prelude> :m +Data.Function
Prelude Data.Function> fix (\x -> x + 1)
Interrupted.
Prelude Data.Function>
```

The `Interrupted.` line is where I hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. When I did that, the blocking application of `fix` immediately exited, and the REPL was ready for action.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be fixed in ghc-8.2.2.

Comment: If you are referring to the ticket ja. has linked to in the comments, note that it is about PowerShell, and not cmd. (That might be relevant, given that I have seen that happen with GHC 8.2.2 too.)