# Haskell + Infinite lists = Hang

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell, have read a few references, and am working on various challenges (mainly codewars). However at times I will attempt to generate an infinite list for some math algorithm and then pick from it (like get the first n numbers which match some pattern).

However because my syntax isn't perfect I often mix up parts and while I want to ask Haskell to define (lazy) an infinite list and pick the first 5 elements (or whatever) I end up actually asking it to do something with the full infinite list and when I build-test it, the program just hangs.

I managed (once) to call up the Windows process manager and what is happening is that in Visual Studio Code when it build and executes the executable it just grows extremely fast absorbing all memory and processor until the computer becomes non-responsive.

Is there some kind of compiler flag that can prevent this?

Comment: It's in general [impossible to determine if a program will ever terminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), so the compiler can't really help you with this. Your best bet is to notice that it has hung up and terminate it forcefully.

Comment: When you experiment with Haskell code, you could run it in GHCi until you feel confident that it works. In GHCi, you can *break* execution if it seems to hang. [Here's how to do it on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50095413/126014).

Comment: It might be useful to set the maximum heap size using RTS options, e.g., `+RTS -M128m -RTS`. See [the manual](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html) for info on how to set this at compile-time.

Comment: Not sure how to help, but try to think of what your functions actually do to the list. ```reverse``` naturally needs the entire list before it can terminate, so does ```sort```. ```take 5``` only needs to inspect the first five elements.

Comment: @RobertK, understanding a Haskell list as a "singly linked list whose tail is possibly a generator" is essential if such thought is to be productive.

Comment: @luqui yes ofcourse, thanks for adding that. I forgot that it is not clear to newcomers how haskell lists are defined.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can run your executable with the `-M` switch, which allows you to specify a maximum memory size. (Default is unlimited.) That way, if your program tries to use more than X amount of memory, it will crash with an exception rather than just consume all available RAM.

Note that this *won't help* if your program is doing lots of processing but not trying to actually *keep* the results in RAM. E.g., if you try to print out the first item that matches a condition, but no item will ever match the condition, in all likelihood your program will loop forever, but not actually consume any RAM. In that case, you'll just have to kill it.

You might also try running your code in GHCi, where you can just jab Ctrl+C to halt your code without killing GHCi itself.

Comment: Thanks, I have started a combination of using ghci, setting limits in the compiler, and just really trying to understand how to work with infinite lists.